Yet no sound Ubuntu since 2021 HUAWEI MateBook D 14 AMD R5 5500U NobelM-WDQ9
I am using Ubuntu 22.04 for 2 years and I have been finding info about that issue. Somebody writes that there is no driver for Everest sound card, somebody writes that installing EndeavourOS will decide the problem (it did not help). Also I tried install the latest kernels (6.9.6 for EndeavourOS, 6.9.9 for Ubuntu in mainline). If you can, say what to change (which option) in "make menuconfig" when building the kernel. What will you suggest?[sudo lspci, inxi -SMA, hwinfo --sound




You have not said what version of Ubuntu you are using, please edit the question and add this. Either way kernel 6.9 is not support at this time on any version of Ubuntu. As currently written the only OS you have named is not support on this site. Of course if you add the Ubuntu version and it is currently  supported it will be on topic.

Pls edit your question and add the text files as text instead of adding them as image. Do not add them comment.
